# Python JSON.loads DICT is considered as LIST

Tags: python, json, list, api, dictionary

I need help because I'm using an API that gives me a result like that

```
{
"header": {
    "statut": 200,
    "message": "OK"
},
"uniteLegale": {
    "siren": "410032460",
    "statutDiffusionUniteLegale": "O",
    "dateCreationUniteLegale": "1997-01-01",
    "sigleUniteLegale": null,
    "sexeUniteLegale": null,
    "prenom1UniteLegale": null,
    "prenom2UniteLegale": null,
    "prenom3UniteLegale": null,
    "prenom4UniteLegale": null,
    "prenomUsuelUniteLegale": null,
    "pseudonymeUniteLegale": null,
    "identifiantAssociationUniteLegale": null,
    "trancheEffectifsUniteLegale": "32",
    "anneeEffectifsUniteLegale": "2020",
    "dateDernierTraitementUniteLegale": "2022-08-29T09:27:06",
    "nombrePeriodesUniteLegale": 6,
    "categorieEntreprise": "ETI",
    "anneeCategorieEntreprise": "2020",
    "periodesUniteLegale": [{
        "dateFin": null,
        "dateDebut": "2020-12-31",
        "etatAdministratifUniteLegale": "A",
        "changementEtatAdministratifUniteLegale": false,
        "nomUniteLegale": null,
        "changementNomUniteLegale": false,
        "nomUsageUniteLegale": null,
        "changementNomUsageUniteLegale": false,
        "denominationUniteLegale": "K. LINE",
        "changementDenominationUniteLegale": false,
        "denominationUsuelle1UniteLegale": null,
        "denominationUsuelle2UniteLegale": null,
        "denominationUsuelle3UniteLegale": null,
        "changementDenominationUsuelleUniteLegale": false,
        "categorieJuridiqueUniteLegale": "5710",
        "changementCategorieJuridiqueUniteLegale": false,
        "activitePrincipaleUniteLegale": "46.73A",
        "nomenclatureActivitePrincipaleUniteLegale": "NAFRev2",
        "changementActivitePrincipaleUniteLegale": false,
        "nicSiegeUniteLegale": "00017",
        "changementNicSiegeUniteLegale": false,
        "economieSocialeSolidaireUniteLegale": "N",
        "changementEconomieSocialeSolidaireUniteLegale": true,
        "caractereEmployeurUniteLegale": "O",
        "changementCaractereEmployeurUniteLegale": false,
        "societeMissionUniteLegale": null,
        "changementSocieteMissionUniteLegale": false
    }, {
        "dateFin": "2020-12-30",
        "dateDebut": "2008-01-01",
        "etatAdministratifUniteLegale": "A",
        "changementEtatAdministratifUniteLegale": false,
        "nomUniteLegale": null,
        "changementNomUniteLegale": false,
        "nomUsageUniteLegale": null,
        "changementNomUsageUniteLegale": false,
        "denominationUniteLegale": "K. LINE",
        "changementDenominationUniteLegale": false,
        "denominationUsuelle1UniteLegale": null,
        "denominationUsuelle2UniteLegale": null,
        "denominationUsuelle3UniteLegale": null,
        "changementDenominationUsuelleUniteLegale": false,
        "categorieJuridiqueUniteLegale": "5710",
        "changementCategorieJuridiqueUniteLegale": false,
        "activitePrincipaleUniteLegale": "46.73A",
        "nomenclatureActivitePrincipaleUniteLegale": "NAFRev2",
        "changementActivitePrincipaleUniteLegale": true,
        "nicSiegeUniteLegale": "00017",
        "changementNicSiegeUniteLegale": false,
        "economieSocialeSolidaireUniteLegale": null,
        "changementEconomieSocialeSolidaireUniteLegale": false,
        "caractereEmployeurUniteLegale": "O",
        "changementCaractereEmployeurUniteLegale": false,
        "societeMissionUniteLegale": null,
        "changementSocieteMissionUniteLegale": false
    }, {
        "dateFin": "2007-12-31",
        "dateDebut": "2003-12-25",
        "etatAdministratifUniteLegale": "A",
        "changementEtatAdministratifUniteLegale": false,
        "nomUniteLegale": null,
        "changementNomUniteLegale": false,
        "nomUsageUniteLegale": null,
        "changementNomUsageUniteLegale": false,
        "denominationUniteLegale": "K. LINE",
        "changementDenominationUniteLegale": false,
        "denominationUsuelle1UniteLegale": null,
        "denominationUsuelle2UniteLegale": null,
        "denominationUsuelle3UniteLegale": null,
        "changementDenominationUsuelleUniteLegale": false,
        "categorieJuridiqueUniteLegale": "5710",
        "changementCategorieJuridiqueUniteLegale": false,
        "activitePrincipaleUniteLegale": "51.5F",
        "nomenclatureActivitePrincipaleUniteLegale": "NAFRev1",
        "changementActivitePrincipaleUniteLegale": true,
        "nicSiegeUniteLegale": "00017",
        "changementNicSiegeUniteLegale": false,
        "economieSocialeSolidaireUniteLegale": null,
        "changementEconomieSocialeSolidaireUniteLegale": false,
        "caractereEmployeurUniteLegale": "O",
        "changementCaractereEmployeurUniteLegale": false,
        "societeMissionUniteLegale": null,
        "changementSocieteMissionUniteLegale": false
    }, {
        "dateFin": "2003-12-24",
        "dateDebut": "2001-12-25",
        "etatAdministratifUniteLegale": "A",
        "changementEtatAdministratifUniteLegale": false,
        "nomUniteLegale": null,
        "changementNomUniteLegale": false,
        "nomUsageUniteLegale": null,
        "changementNomUsageUniteLegale": false,
        "denominationUniteLegale": "K. LINE",
        "changementDenominationUniteLegale": false,
        "denominationUsuelle1UniteLegale": null,
        "denominationUsuelle2UniteLegale": null,
        "denominationUsuelle3UniteLegale": null,
        "changementDenominationUsuelleUniteLegale": false,
        "categorieJuridiqueUniteLegale": "5710",
        "changementCategorieJuridiqueUniteLegale": true,
        "activitePrincipaleUniteLegale": null,
        "nomenclatureActivitePrincipaleUniteLegale": null,
        "changementActivitePrincipaleUniteLegale": false,
        "nicSiegeUniteLegale": "00017",
        "changementNicSiegeUniteLegale": false,
        "economieSocialeSolidaireUniteLegale": null,
        "changementEconomieSocialeSolidaireUniteLegale": false,
        "caractereEmployeurUniteLegale": "O",
        "changementCaractereEmployeurUniteLegale": false,
        "societeMissionUniteLegale": null,
        "changementSocieteMissionUniteLegale": false
    }, {
        "dateFin": "2001-12-24",
        "dateDebut": "1997-12-25",
        "etatAdministratifUniteLegale": "A",
        "changementEtatAdministratifUniteLegale": false,
        "nomUniteLegale": null,
        "changementNomUniteLegale": false,
        "nomUsageUniteLegale": null,
        "changementNomUsageUniteLegale": false,
        "denominationUniteLegale": "K. LINE",
        "changementDenominationUniteLegale": false,
        "denominationUsuelle1UniteLegale": null,
        "denominationUsuelle2UniteLegale": null,
        "denominationUsuelle3UniteLegale": null,
        "changementDenominationUsuelleUniteLegale": false,
        "categorieJuridiqueUniteLegale": "5599",
        "changementCategorieJuridiqueUniteLegale": false,
        "activitePrincipaleUniteLegale": null,
        "nomenclatureActivitePrincipaleUniteLegale": null,
        "changementActivitePrincipaleUniteLegale": false,
        "nicSiegeUniteLegale": "00017",
        "changementNicSiegeUniteLegale": false,
        "economieSocialeSolidaireUniteLegale": null,
        "changementEconomieSocialeSolidaireUniteLegale": false,
        "caractereEmployeurUniteLegale": "O",
        "changementCaractereEmployeurUniteLegale": true,
        "societeMissionUniteLegale": null,
        "changementSocieteMissionUniteLegale": false
    }, {
        "dateFin": "1997-12-24",
        "dateDebut": "1997-01-01",
        "etatAdministratifUniteLegale": "A",
        "changementEtatAdministratifUniteLegale": false,
        "nomUniteLegale": null,
        "changementNomUniteLegale": false,
        "nomUsageUniteLegale": null,
        "changementNomUsageUniteLegale": false,
        "denominationUniteLegale": "K. LINE",
        "changementDenominationUniteLegale": false,
        "denominationUsuelle1UniteLegale": null,
        "denominationUsuelle2UniteLegale": null,
        "denominationUsuelle3UniteLegale": null,
        "changementDenominationUsuelleUniteLegale": false,
        "categorieJuridiqueUniteLegale": "5599",
        "changementCategorieJuridiqueUniteLegale": false,
        "activitePrincipaleUniteLegale": null,
        "nomenclatureActivitePrincipaleUniteLegale": null,
        "changementActivitePrincipaleUniteLegale": false,
        "nicSiegeUniteLegale": "00017",
        "changementNicSiegeUniteLegale": false,
        "economieSocialeSolidaireUniteLegale": null,
        "changementEconomieSocialeSolidaireUniteLegale": false,
        "caractereEmployeurUniteLegale": null,
        "changementCaractereEmployeurUniteLegale": false,
        "societeMissionUniteLegale": null,
        "changementSocieteMissionUniteLegale": false
    }]
}
}
```

I need with python to take only few elements inside it : uniteLegale : "siren", "categorieEntreprise", "trancheEffectifsUniteLegale";  periodesUniteLegale : "denominationUniteLegale".

For this I do that :

```
data = json.loads(api_call_response.text) # data = my json answer
siren = data['uniteLegale']['siren']
categorieEntreprise = data['uniteLegale']['categorieEntreprise']
effectif = data['uniteLegale']['trancheEffectifsUniteLegale']
periodesUnite = data['uniteLegale']['periodesUniteLegale']
denomination = periodeUnite['denominationUniteLegale']
```

but I got the error :     `denomination = periodeUnite['denominationUniteLegale'] TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`
Python thinks that periodesUnite is a list and not a dictionnary so I can't get my data.
What can I do ?

Thanks you

Comment: Well, it *is* a `list`. Which element of the list do you want? (There is no key named: `"denominationLegale"`)

Comment: There is no key `"denominationLegale"`

Comment: in uniteLegale : "siren", "categorieEntreprise", "trancheEffectifsUniteLegale". And in periodesUniteLegale : "denominationUniteLegale". Thanks I made the change

Comment: Which of the keys named `"denominationUniteLegale"` do you want?

Comment: I want the first one

Comment: Ok, the first one would be: `denomination = periodeUnite[0]['denominationUniteLegale']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a list:

See the square brackets. [Your JSON sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MK5VG.png)

periodesUnite is extracted from data['uniteLegale']['periodesUniteLegale'].
As your key 'periodesUniteLegale' is a list so as your var periodesUnite.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Since it is indeed a list, one way to make sure you capture all the values is to use a list comprehension that takes the desired key from each dictionary:

```
>>> [d["denominationUniteLegale"] for d in periodesUnite]
['K. LINE', 'K. LINE', 'K. LINE', 'K. LINE', 'K. LINE', 'K. LINE']
```

If you use a set comprehension instead, you get only the unique values (of which there is only one):

```
>>> {d["denominationUniteLegale"] for d in periodesUnite}
{'K. LINE'}
```

So you could replace this line:

```
denomination = periodeUnite['denominationUniteLegale']
```

with a line that gets the multiple values, e.g.:

```
denominations = {d["denominationUniteLegale"] for d in periodesUnite}
```

If you're confident that there will only ever be one value and you want to get that one value, you might do:

```
denominations = {d["denominationUniteLegale"] for d in periodesUnite}
denomination = denominations.pop()
assert not denominations, f"Extra denominations: {denominations}!"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I forgot to add one more thing. My program will get different values from different request. the answer won't be each time 'K. LINE', but the answer will always be linked to "denominationUniteLegale".

Comment: The code in my answer works regardless of what the value is, provided that the key is always the same.